# vba excel edit/add series and horizontal axis labels

Tags: vba, excel

My Current code places three bar graphs in each section on the x axis. I wish to have three separate sections each with their own bar graph. [image]  here is my current code

```
Sub DrawChart1()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim j As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rCht As Range, rYVals As Range
 Dim cht As Chart

 ' finding the number of rows
 Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
 'j = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


 'j = ws.Cells(9, 1).Row
 j = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, 3)).Row
 ' start with X values (row 10 to j), include header row (row 9)
 Set rCht = ws.Range(ws.Cells(9, 1), ws.Cells(j, 1))

 Set rCht = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, 3))

 ' add column of Y values if row 8 of column is TRUE
' For i = 2 To 14
  For i = 1 To 3
  If ws.Cells(8, 1).Value Then
  Set rYVals = ws.Range(ws.Cells(9, i), ws.Cells(9, i))
   '     Set rYVals = ws.Range(ws.Cells(9, 2), ws.Cells(9, 2))

     Set rCht = Union(rCht, rYVals)
   End If
 Next

   ' if we've had any Y values, insert chart, using range we've built up
    If Not rYVals Is Nothing Then
     Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumn).Chart
    cht.SetSourceData Source:=rCht, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    End If
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to edit/add series and horizontal axis labels.
Instead edit axis labels, it is possible to edit label of seriescollection point.

```
Sub DrawChart1()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim j As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rCht As Range, rYVals As Range
 Dim cht As Chart
 Dim n As Integer
    Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")

    Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumn).Chart
    With cht
        For i = 1 To 3
            If ws.Cells(8, 1).Value Then
                n = n + 1
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                With .SeriesCollection(n)
                    .Name = ws.Cells(1, i).Text
                    .XValues = n
                    .Values = ws.Cells(9, i)
                    With .Points(1)
                        .ApplyDataLabels
                        .DataLabel.Text = ws.Cells(1, i).Text
                    End With
                End With
            End If
        Next i
        .ChartGroups(1).Overlap = -100
    End With

End Sub
```